# Let $a$ and $b$ be integers. If $17\mid 26a + 39b$, prove that $17\mid 9a + 5b$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Okay so I have this exercise question.
I tried looking for solutions online and found some related ones but this case is a bit different. 
I tried by eliminating $a$ also but couldn't get some reasonable answer.
Here's my work so far according to another question.
Let $p$ = $26a + 39b$
$q$ = $9a + 5b$,
$a$ = $\frac{p-39b}{26}$
Substituting in $q$ gives
$26q = 9p - 346b$
Now $9p$ is divisible by $17$ but how do I prove for $346b$?

Comment: $26=17+9$ and $39=2(17)+5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$17 \mid 26a + 39b$

prove $17 \mid 9a +5b$

One side of the proof $\Rightarrow$ you can work backwards to get $\Leftarrow$ :

$17\mid 26a + 39b \iff 9a +17a + 5b +34b \iff(9a+5b) + 17(a + 2b)$

If $17\mid 26a + 39b$ then $17\mid 9a+5b + 17(a+2b)$.

Since $17\mid 17(a+2b)$ and 
$17\mid 9a+5b + 17(a+2b)$,

$17\mid 9a+5b$ 
because $17\mid 9a+5b + 17(a+2b)$.

Comment: Have a look on [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This makes your answer readable.

Comment: Thank you poyea

Answer (score 4):

$26a + 39b = (9a +5b) + 17(a + 2b)$ so.....

Comment: Okay but how should I know how to divide the statement in this way? Like is there any theorem or anything?

Comment: And we did get $9a+5b$ but how to prove it's divisible by 17?

Comment: Notice $26a+39b-(9a+5b)=17a+34b$. You should then spot that this is $17(a+2b)$

Comment: You stated that $p=26a+39b$, let's alter that to $17p=26a+39b, p \in \Bbb Z$. Then $17p=(9a+5b)+17(k), k\in \Bbb Z$, which means that $9a+5b=17(p-k), (p-k)\in \Bbb Z$, from which we infer that $9a+5b$ is divisible by 17.

Comment: It's basic definitions.  a≡bmodn⟺a−b≡0modn⟺n|a−ba \equiv b \mod n \iff a-b \equiv 0 \mod n \iff n|a-b.

Comment: The sum or difference of multiples of 17 is another multiple of 17. That's the relevant theorem. You take the given expression, subtract something that you know is a multiple of 17, and end up with the desired expression. Boom.

Comment: "And we did get 9a+5b but how to prove it's divisible by 17".  Let $26a+39b = 17K$.  Then   $9a + 5b = (26a + 39b) - 17(a + 2b) = 17(K -a -2b)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
13(2a+3b)=17m\Rightarrow 2a+3b=17m'\\
9a+5b=17n
$$

then solving for $a,b$

$$
2a+3b=17m'\\
9a+5b=17n
$$

$$
a = 3n-5m'\\
b=9m'-2n
$$

hence those are the feasible $a,b$

Answer (score 0):

$$26 a =17a +9a $$

$$ 39 b = 34b +5b $$

Upon adding together you get

$$26 a +39 b = 17( a+2b) + 9a +5b$$

$$ 17| ( 26 a +39 b) \implies 17| 9a +5b$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $17 \mid 26a + 39b$ and $a,b\in Z$, note that:
$$\frac{26a+39b}{17}-a=\frac{9a+39b}{17}; \\
\frac{9a+39b}{17}-2b=\frac{9a+5b}{17}.$$
Alternatively:
$$\frac{26a+39b}{17}=\frac{17a+9a+17b+17b+5b}{17}=a+2b+\frac{9a+5b}{17}.$$